# How do I test my app when it's dependent on Google sign in after publishing app on the Google Play Store?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-signin

So when I published my app on the Google Play Store, I had to change the SHA1 key on Firebase and Google Play API Console to the new one that the Google Play Console generated.

The problem now is if I want to test my app from Android Studio, I need to change the SHA1 key back to the original one. If I do that, then the current users who have already logged in my app will no longer be able to log back in.

How do I test my app when it's dependent on the Google sign in and not affect current users?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple SHA1 fingerprints can be added to a single firebase project. Add your debug key (Android studio SHA1 fingerprint) to your firebase project along with your app's production key. Then download the latest Json file and add it to your project in Android studio.

Comment: What about the Google API Console? That only accepts one SHA1 key, not multiples.

Comment: Download the json file after adding both debug key and production key to your firebase project. Include it in your project. Make sure that Google signin feature works. Finally, generate the signed apk using your production key (Production key cannot be changed once it is generated or linked to an app). Upload it to Google play console.

Comment: In this way, you will be able to use signin feature in both debug apk and production apk. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Sarweshkumar C R's answer is perfect, just adding visualization for total newbies. Both keys can coexist with no problems, in the image I added 3 SHA certificate fingerprints to demonstrate and you can add by clicking 'Add fingerprint'

[image: General Settings]